# PowerShell displaying properties on same line

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to output the properties for the following but it is displaying all of them in the same line. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
##################### Removes office installations #####################

$RegPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall", "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"

$apps = Get-ChildItem -Path $RegPath | Get-ItemProperty 

$search = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the name of application you want to uninstall: "

$apps365 = $apps | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -Match "$search" | Sort-Object DisplayName | Format-Table }

Write-Host $apps365
```

Comment: Did you try `Format-Table` or `Format-List`?

Comment: Remove `| Format-Table` from the `Where-Object` scriptblock and display the list with `$apps365  |  Format-Table -AutoSize`

Comment: I did try Format-Table and Format-List  with the same results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I needed to remove the `Format-Table` from the `$apps365` variable